# How can I comment out a node in XML using PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

Is it possible to comment out a node in an XDocument?

I have following tag.

```
<abc key="test" value="samplevalue"></abc>
```

I don't have to remove the node; I just want it to be there in the XML file in commented format. I can use something like this:

```
$node = $xml.selectSingleNode('//abc')
#$node.OuterXml.Insert(0,"#");
$node.$xml.Save("c:\test.xml")
```

But if one node spreads in two lines like

```
<abc key="test" value="sampleValue">
</abc>
```

then how do I handle this case?

Comment: Every language has its own way of commenting things. In Powershell it's `#`, in C it's `//`, and [XML has its own way](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) - see below answer. Do not assume it's `//` or `#` everywhere (whichever you are most used to).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments in XML are done with `<!--` and `-->`. Try this:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<root>
<abc key="test" value="samplevalue"></abc>
<abc key="sa" value="dsad">sda
</abc>
</root>
"@

$node = $xml.selectSingleNode('//abc')
#OuterXML is read-only, so I took an alternative route
$node.ParentNode.InnerXml = $node.ParentNode.InnerXml.Replace($node.OuterXml, $node.OuterXml.Insert(0, "<!--").Insert($node.OuterXml.Length+4, "-->"))
$xml.Save("c:\test.xml")
```

test.xml

```
<root>
  <!--<abc key="test" value="samplevalue"></abc>-->
  <abc key="sa" value="dsad">sda
</abc>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Its commenting the nodes.But one thing i am seeing is that since the node belongs to a namespace,Node.outXml contains Namespaces appended at the end of node.But that is not the exepected result.Is there a way i can prevent that namespaces to appear in Node.OuterXml.

Comment: you're sample did not include any namespaces. if you need help, provide a valid xml sample and the code you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: My XML is as follows:                                                     `<WDA.Application.Configuration `Xmlns="WDA.Application.Configuration">
`<ServiceFactory>
<Connection name="TIM" trace="All">
 <Property name="AVEVA.Components.TransactionSupportEnabled" value="true" />
</Connection>
</ServiceFactory>
`</WDA.Application.Configuration>                                  and I am using exatly same code as you have written above ,but node.Outerxml call in coe is appending namespace of xml as well.

Comment: is are there multiple namespaces in the xmlfile? if so, provide a valid sample that includes the root object etc. And provide it by updating your question, not in a comment. With the sample you provided above and `$node = $xml.selectSingleNode('//Connection')` (getting the connection tag instead), it works perfectly. no extra namespace here.

Answer (score 19):

You can simply create a comment node, and replace your abc nodes with these comments:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<root>
<abc key="test" value="samplevalue"></abc>
<abc key="sa" value="dsad">sda
</abc>
</root>
"@;

$xml.SelectNodes("//abc") | ForEach-Object { 
    $abc = $_;
    $comment = $xml.CreateComment($abc.OuterXml);
    $abc.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($comment, $abc);
}

$xml.Save(<# filename #>);
```

Outputs:

```
<root><!--<abc key="test" value="samplevalue"></abc>--><!--<abc key="sa" value="dsad">sda
</abc>--></root>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here a powershell function to **Comment an xml node**:

```
function CommentXmlNode([String] $filePath, [String] $nodeXPath)
{
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "$filePath"

    # Find the nodes that we want to comment
    $xml.SelectNodes("$nodeXPath") | ForEach-Object {

        $nodeToComment = $_;
        $comment = $xml.CreateComment($nodeToComment.OuterXml);

        # Comment the node
        $nodeToComment.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($comment, $nodeToComment);
    }

    # Save the file
    $xml.Save("$filePath");
}
```

Here is a powershell function to **Uncomment xml node**:

```
function UncommentXmlNode([String] $filePath, [String] $searchCriteria)
{    
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path "$filePath"

    # Find all comments on the xml file
    $xml.SelectNodes("//comment()") | ForEach-Object {     

        # We convert the comment to an xml
        $nodeToConvert = $_;  
        $convertedNode = $nodeToConvert.InnerText | convertto-xml 
        [xml]$xmlConvertedNode = $convertedNode

        # Find the comment that match our search criteria
        $xmlConvertedNode.SelectNodes("/descendant::*[contains(text(), '$searchCriteria')]") | ForEach-Object { 

            $nodeToUncomment = $_;

            $strToFind = "<!--" + $nodeToUncomment.InnerText + "-->"

            $strReplacement = $nodeToUncomment.InnerText

            # Replace the commented string with uncommented one
            $con = Get-Content "$filePath"
            $con | % { $_.Replace($strToFind, $strReplacement) } | Set-Content "$filePath"
        }
    }

}
```

You can use them like this :

```
CommentXmlNode "D:\temp\file.xml" "YourXPath"
```

--

```
UncommentXmlNode "D:\temp\file.xml" "Some String in the xml node to Uncomment"
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. I was wondering if you found a way to comment while preserving the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this block of quote if you want to preserve formatting and don't use string replacement

it build a temp node containing the commented Node Value, which does not include comments tag, then it process replacement.

```
# path to the file
$File = "c:\pathtoyourfile\example.xml"

# XPath to the element to un comment
$XPath = "/Settings/SettingNode[@name='Installation']/SettingNode[@name='Features']/Setting[@name='Features' and @scope='Installation']/StringArray/String"

# get xml file
$xmlFile = [xml](Get-Content $File) 

# get parent and child path from XPath
$parentXPath = $XPath.Substring(0, $XPath.LastIndexOf('/'))
$childXPath = $XPath -replace "$parentXPath/", ''

# get comment
$xmlNode = $xmlFile.SelectNodes("$parentXPath/comment()") | ? { $_.InnerText -match "<$childXPath" }

# create node containing comment content
$tempNode = $xmlFile.CreateElement("tempNode")          
$tempNode.InnerXml = $xmlNode.Value
$replaceNode = $tempNode.SelectSingleNode("/$childXPath")

# process replacement 
$xmlNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild($replaceNode, $xmlNode)

# save change
$xmlFile.Save($File)
```