# How to replace text and symbols in a txt file?

Tags: vbscript

I have a `web.config` file and to change settings I have to manually go in and keep changing the code.

What I have found so far is an example script I am trying to adapt:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "Jim ", "James ")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Text.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

The problem I have is I need to change symbols rather than text and I assume this is messing it up.

So where the above says `James` and `Jim`, my data is to change:

```
"<component type="Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts.Mocks.CallCredit.CallCreditCallValidateServiceProxyMock, Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts.Mocks" service="Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts.CallCredit.ICallCreditCallValidateService, Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts" /> ",
```

to this:

```
"<!--<component type="Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts.Mocks.CallCredit.CallCreditCallValidateServiceProxyMock, Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts.Mocks" service="Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts.CallCredit.ICallCreditCallValidateService, Satsuma.Connectivity.Services.Contracts" />-->",)
```

and vice-versa. If you look, it is only the start and finish symbols (e.g `<!--<` and `>-->`) that need to be edited.

Comment: Please note - I have to search for the complete line I cannot just search and replace the symbols

Comment: Please do not post complex code snippets in comments as it becomes a bit unreadable then; [edit] your question rather. To the `Line 2 Char 1 invalid procedure call or argument` error: neither `ForReading` nor `ForWriting` constants are _not_ intrinsic in `VBScript` so you need to define them explicitly e.g. as follows: `Const ForWriting = 2, ForReading = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `"`**inner**`"` double quotes should be `""`**doubled**`""` as follows:

```
replWhat = "<component type=""Satsuma..Mocks"" service=""Satsuma..Contracts"" />"
'                           ^               ^          ^                   ^
replWith = "<!--" & replWhat & "-->" 

strNewText = Replace(strText, replWhat, replWith, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)

'and vice versa'
strOldText = Replace(strNewText, replWith, replWhat, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
```

The texts are shortened in given example to keep commands in reasonable width for better readability.

Read [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx) to see meaning of additional `, 1, -1, vbTextCompare` arguments of the `Replace` function.

Comment: I have to search for the whole lines of code in the web.config file as there are many lines of code that contain the symbols I don't need to be replaced so this wouldn't work as I assume it will replace all symbols in the file.                                                                                                       srch = "<component type=""Sats...ocks"" service=""Sats...acts"" />"
repl = "<!--" & srch & "-->"
strNewText = Replace(strText, srch, repl)

Comment: Here the `...` does not mean any kind of [wildcard character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) for VBScript interpreter but used as an [ellipsis (in linguistic sense)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) for better readability by _humans_. However, follow @Ansgar and use an XML parser...

Comment: Thank you, I have got some ideas to resolve this issue, to start with I want to get this simple script working however when I try run it I see Line 2 Char 1 invalid procedure call or argument                                               Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "Jim ", "James ")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Textt.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close

Answer (score 2):

A simple string replacement could be done like this (extensive attribute values abbreviated for readability reasons):

```vb
srch = "<component type=""Sats...ocks"" service=""Sats...acts"" />"
repl = "<!--" & srch & "-->"
strNewText = Replace(strText, srch, repl)
```

Note that nested double quotes in VBScript strings must be doubled to escape them. Unescaped double quotes would prematurely terminate the string, and you'll most likely get a syntax error.

With this said, modifying `web.config` files with string replacements is a Bad Idea™, because they're XML files, and in XML there is no difference between any of the following notations:

```xml
<component type="foo" service="bar" />

<component    type='foo'    service='bar'    />

<component
  type="foo"
  service="bar"
/>

<component type="foo" service="bar"></component>
```

What you actually want to do is use an [XML parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Something like this should do (code shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16821777/1630171)):

```vb
config = "C:\path\to\your\web.config"

Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.load config

If xml.parseError <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo xml.parseError.reason
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

Set node = xml.selectSingleNode("//component[@type='Sats...ocks']")
Set comment = xml.createComment(node.xml)
node.parentNode.replaceChild(comment, node)

xml.save config
```